# Runtime System in C

Tags: c, computer-science

According to Wikipedia an [execution model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_model) is

> part of the language specification, and is implemented as part of the language implementation.

It further defines that

> the order of execution may be chosen statically [...] but a small portion must be chosen dynamically, as execution proceeds.
>
> [...] The static choices are most often implemented inside a compiler, in which case the order of work is represented by the order in which instructions are placed into the executable binary. The dynamic choices would then be implemented inside the language's runtime system.
> The runtime system may be a library, which is called by instructions inserted by the compiler, or the runtime system may be embedded into the executable directly, such as by inserting branch instructions, which make dynamic choices about which work to perform next.

Wikipedia specifies the [runtime system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_system) as

> any behavior that is not directly the work of a program is runtime system behavior. This definition includes as part of the runtime system things such as putting parameters onto the stack before a function call, the behavior of disk I/O, and parallel execution related behaviors.

which additionally

> is also the gateway by which a running program interacts with the runtime environment, which contains not only state values that are accessible during program execution, but also active entities that can be interacted with during program execution like disk drives and people, via keyboards.

It further states that,

> Higher-level behaviors implemented by a runtime system may include tasks such as drawing text on the screen or making an Internet connection.
> It is often the case that an OS provide these kinds of behaviors as well [...] The runtime system is implemented as an abstraction layer that translates the invocation of the runtime system into an invocation of the operating system. This hides the complexity or variations in the services offered by different operating systems. **[which basically are system calls for me, regarding the Linux Kernel]**
> This also implies that the OS kernel can itself be viewed as a runtime system, and that the set of OS calls that invoke OS behaviors may be viewed as interactions with a runtime system.

I understand that there has to be some kind of runtime environment, like the Linux Kernel, loading the compiled executable into memory, starting the process, allowing sub-threads and stuff like this. The kernel itself is written in `C` and can not be viewed as the "runtime system" of the `C` language. However, it provides functions like `malloc()` and `free()` which are essential parts of the runtime system.

**Q** So what exactly is the runtime system of `C` ? Is there any, not blurry, definition of it ? Is it a mixture of a self-standing kernel + Compiler ?

Comment: `The kernel itself is written in C and can not be viewed as the "runtime system" of the C language`. Why not? There are freestanding and hosted implementations of C. The kernel is freestanding, i.e. it provides everything it needs to run. Normal C applications are hosted and depend on the libc, itself depending on the kernel, to run properly.

Comment: How could the `runtime system of C` be a `mixture of Linux Kernel + Compiler` on a VAX system?  Or MS-Windows, or BSD, or ......?

Comment: @a3f and how does it behave with bare metal programming on embedded systems with `C` ? Do the vendors of the µC provided a runtime library which implements the basic functionality of the kernel in order to compile and run C programs properly ?

Comment: "it (kernel) provides functions like malloc() and free()" --> the standard library provides `malloc()`, etc., not the kernel.  If the library uses a kernel or not is not part of C.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Why grab examples from the past? Just see bare-metal systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line between "runtime" and "standard library" is blurry and not really agreed upon.  "Kernel" is usually a harder line, between privileged code and non-privileged code.  The way different parts are labeled will also differ from platform to platform, so it's not really possible to give a general answer.

However, you can answer the question somewhat for particular systems.  For example, here is how it would work on a typical Linux system with a GNU toolchain:

- The program code, compiled as a bunch of `*.o` files and linked into an executable.
- The "C runtime library".  This is available as a few extra `*.o` files (`crt1.o`, `crti.o`, `crtn.o`) which the compiler implicitly links into your program.  This library rather small, and only really does two things.  It provides `_start`, which loads `argc` and `argv`, calls `main`, and calls `exit` when `main` returns (sort of).  The library also calls global constructors and destructors--which don't usually exist in C, but you can create them using language extensions.
- The "C standard library".  This is available as a monster `*.so` or `*.a` library which the compiler implicitly links into your program.  It implements pure functions like `strcpy` and `atoi`, as well as more complicated systems like `malloc` and `free`, and also provides a set of system calls which can be thin wrappers around Linux syscalls like `open`, more complicated wrappers around more generic syscalls like `fork` and `clone`, or can be VDSO-accelerated like `gettimeofday` and `clock_gettime`.

This is not a definitive answer to "what is the C runtime" because there is not really a strict definition of "runtime" to begin with.  However, there is a library which is *called* the "C runtime library" on Linux, and similar libraries exist on other systems.  You can often read the source code directly if you search for it, or you can disassemble it (it's not very long).

This will all change on some platforms, like embedded platforms, where you might have just a big "standard library" which has everything you need, and no kernel.

Comment: The question is too broad. It explicitly targets not only Linux systems (or systems with an OS in general).

Comment: @Olaf: Agreed that the question is broad—Linux was given only as an illustrative example of how it works on one particular platform.

Comment: @Olaf: Do you think that the answer contains errors, or am I just not being clear enough that the Linux example is illustrative only?

Comment: As I wrote, the question is too broad. An acceptable answer would require some pages of details. There are just way too many different C implementations/runtime environments. The standard intentionally does not specify this like e.g. Java. If I was not out of votes currently, I'd CVed the question instantly.

Comment: @Olaf: If you think the question is too broad and shouldn't be answered, then the appropriate course of action is to leave a comment on the question, flag the question, vote to close the question, or downvote the question.  As I can see that precisely zero of these things have been done, I'm not sure I understand why you are talking to me about the question here.  I'm also not of the opinion that we need to give encyclopedic answers to everything—you are of course free to disagree, but you haven't made any comments about my answer, just about the question itself.

Comment: @Olaf: I'd consider the daily limit—50—to be particularly high, and if you find it's not enough for your needs maybe you stand a good chance to become a community moderator.  But I would still direct you to put your comments about the question in the question comments, where they will be directed to the person who asked the question, rather than directed towards someone who apparently just disagrees with you about whether a question is too broad.  We can continue in chat, if you'd like.

Comment: Running out of CVs is not uncommon for people taking moderation serious. You don't need to be a moderator to do that. It was not me wanting this bunch of comments; I just left a comment to inform you your answer does not cover what has been asked, because I don't like DVs without comment, too. I just tried to explain on your request, as I consider it is good manners. I might be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137798/discussion-between-dietrich-epp-and-olaf).

Answer (score 0):

No, the kernel does not provide functions like `malloc()` and `free()`, though these functions do ultimately rely on memory provided by the kernel.

The runtime system of C is the C runtime libraries, which are provided by the vendor of your compiler.  When you `#include <stdio.h>` or anything like that, you are specifying that you want to use functionality from these libraries.  If you look carefully at the link step of your make process, you will see that the object files produced by your compiler are liked together with the C runtime libraries, (also known as the "C runtime" for short,) to produce your executable.

Then, later, the OS will load and execute your program, but the OS has no idea, nor does it care, which language your program was written in, and what kind of runtime support it is making use of.

Comment: Are the C runtime libraries specific for the the underlying OS ?

Comment: @SebNag yes, each C runtime library implementation is OS-dependent.  It is essentially a translation layer between the interface stipulated by the standard C library to the interface provided by the underlying operating system.  Precisely so that you can code against the standard C library interface in a portable manner without having to worry too much which operating system you are running on.

Comment: There is no requirement for libraries in C.